# EF Post Request Failed, what is wrong with this ERD?

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

**Context:**

This is the entity relationship I am trying to represent:
[image: Image of ER Diagram]

Tenant Id is referenced as a composite primary key such that it can be sharded using cosmos db using that variable to distrubute tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "tenant" (
"tenant_id" TEXT,
"name" TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ("tenant_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "workspace" (
  "workspace_id" UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "description" TEXT,
  "created_at" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  "updated_at" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  "created_by" TEXT,
  "tenant_id" TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ("workspace_id", "tenant_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_workspace.tenant_id"
    FOREIGN KEY ("tenant_id")
      REFERENCES "tenant"("tenant_id")
);
```

The workspace that gets generated looks like this:

```
public partial class Workspace
{
    public Guid WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The Scaffold creates an entity as such (using Npgsql and EF):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workspace>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.WorkspaceId, e.TenantId }).HasName("workspace_pkey");

    entity.ToTable("workspace");

    entity.Property(e => e.WorkspaceId)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("gen_random_uuid()")
        .HasColumnName("workspace_id");
    entity.Property(e => e.TenantId).HasColumnName("tenant_id");
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone")
        .HasColumnName("created_at");
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("created_by");
    entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnName("description");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("name");
    entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone")
        .HasColumnName("updated_at");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Tenant).WithMany(p => p.Workspace)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.TenantId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_workspace.tenant_id");
});
```

**Question:**

When I try to create a tenant using the generated controllers it all works fine.
When I try the same post request with a workspace I am met with the following:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-55f66035f7a54ef40e6e9c4868570035-52f1db93827aa60d-00",
  "errors": {
    "Tenant": [
      "The Tenant field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the post function in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Workspace>> PostWorkspace(Workspace workspace)
    {
      if (_context.Workspace == null)
      {
          return Problem("Entity set 'CitusContext.Workspace'  is null.");
      }
        _context.Workspace.Add(workspace);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetWorkspace", new { id = workspace.WorkspaceId }, workspace);
    }
```

I want the relationship to be defined with the TenantId string not with a new virtual object. How can I achieve this?

Is there something fundimental I am misunderstanding about EF?

Thanks,
Matt